# Заменить select на кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

Как поменять селект-форму на кнопки как на скрине ?

```
<select id="product_size" class="input-medium" onchange="product.setSize(this.value);">
                            {% if(current_type and current_color) %}
                                {% for size in product.products[current_type].colors[current_color].sizes %}
                                    <option{% if(size.tkey == current_size) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
                                        value="{{ size.tkey }}">{{ size.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: самое очевидное - нарисовать кнопки через div, span или как еще вздумается....select сделать hidden. а при нажатии на кнопку - выбирать соответствующий пункт в селекте.....хотя... на самом деле select уже и не нужен

Comment: на картинке вроде checkbox

Comment: @soledar10, ну это типа он хочет select со свойством multiselect так отобразить. Но вообще да, тут логичнее использовать уже checkbox.